# Not able to make Python3.10.4 default of Python3 command in AWS EC2

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I installed Python3.10.4 on my AWS. My Python3 was showing the wrong version so I uninstalled a few other versions and tried to make it point to Python3.10.4 but now it is broken.
It shows that the Python3 command is not found.

The link that I followed to install Python3.10.4: https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-python-3-10-on-centos-rhel-8-fedora/

[image]

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/python3 -V` give you the correct version?

Comment: @jellycsc ---     -bash: /usr/bin/python3: No such file or directory

Comment: Your python installation is probably installed as `/usr/local/bin/python3.10`, you need to update the `python3` symbolic link to point to that instead of to `/usr/bin`

Comment: Did you tried by reinstalling python?

Comment: Make sure to backup your system before playing around with python binaries, you could easily break it if you change the wrong binaries.